# Microsoft.Win32.ShimRegistryKey not working on build machine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I Have lots of unit tests where I shim the Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey using Microsoft Fakes. When I run the build on my local machine the unit test passed. But if I run it on build machine the unit test fails with the following error for these tests.

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey' from assembly
>   'mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703'.

The curious thing is that both my local machine and build machine are 64-bit and the unit test project are targeting AnyCPU. Is there some configuration could be missing on the build machine?

Comment: Does the build machine have Visual Studio Ultimate installed, and is it using the Visual Studio Test Runner? If no, that's your problem and this is a duplicate. If yes, it's probably something more complicated.

Comment: The build machine is using Visual Studio Premium and the other unit test involves with shim all passed. And It is using Visual Studio Test Runner.

Answer (score 0):

I just has a similar issue when using Shims in multiple separate Unit test projects. Apparently the generated shims can overwrite each over or something like that.

Here's the instructions I followed to fix it:
Scroll to the middle of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx

It's under the heading of optimise build times, but use it to fix your problem too.

Because such assemblies rarely change on your machine, you can reuse the generated Fakes assemblies in other projects.

From your unit test projects, you can simply take a reference to the compiled Fakes assemblies that are placed under the FakesAssemblies in the project folder.

- Create a new Class Library with the .NET runtime version matching
  your test projects. Let’s call it Fakes.Prebuild. Remove the
  class1.cs file from the project, not needed.

  Add reference to all the System and third-party assemblies you need
  Fakes for. and generate the fakes, edit the .fakes file if you like,
  and build to generate the fake assemblies.

  From your Unit Test projects Just make sure that you have a reference
  to the Fakes runtime DLL: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll

  Then for each assembly that you have created Fakes for, add a
  reference to the corresponding DLL file in the
  Fakes.Prebuild\FakesAssemblies folder of your project. (This folder
  get created when you compile)

  To confirm You will need to add the reference by Browsing to the
  generated fake assembly..